# jQuery change function and IE 7

Tags: jquery

I know that change() is not working with IE7.

Although I still need to find a solution to my problem: Here is my jQuery:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
if ( $("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') ) {
    $(".subbut").show();
    } else {
    $(".subbut").hide();
        }
});
```

Simple Function where by "ticking" checkbox I'm truing to show the .subbut and hide when "unticked". And just cant find the solution. Is there a way around it please?

Thanks for help in advance in advance

Dom

Comment: Do you have more than 1 checkbox in the page? It's not logic if you consider theres more than 1 checkbox(s) there. Please try directly use an ID

Comment: Yes, there is only one. I tried also add the ID, still, nothing.

Comment: Why not use "click" instead of change?

Comment: try `.val()` instead of `.is(':checked')`

Comment: another advice: use `input[type=checkbox]`, no quotation marks

Comment: i've tried your code in jsfiddle and it's working nicely, could you post your code in jsfiddle to try and replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use this rather than another reference,

```
if( $(this).is(':checked')){
}
```

or use attr().